# HTML Canvas WebGL context readPixels to Array returns zeros

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, webgl, pixel

I'm trying to search for a specific pixel RBG within a canvas element that only supports webgl context (2d returns null), by reading all pixels using the following code:

```
var context = document.getElementById('game-canvas').getContext('webgl');
var pixels = new Uint8Array(context.drawingBufferWidth * context.drawingBufferHeight * 4);
context.readPixels(
  0, 
  0, 
  context.drawingBufferWidth, 
  context.drawingBufferHeight, 
  context.RGBA, 
  context.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
  pixels);
```

However, the pixels array is all zeros while there are graphics displayed on the canvas.

Comment: If memory serves me right `readPixels` reads from a `FrameBuffer`. You need to render to a frame buffer and then read the pixel while it is bound

Comment: @Blindman67 the "screen" is also a framebuffer and referred to as ["default framebuffer"](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Default_Framebuffer), and you can read pixels from it, this true for both webgl and opengl.

Comment: @LJᛃ  Well then the OP may need to use `{preserveDrawingBufer: true}` option when creating the context. As it defaults to false thus clearing the  DrawBuffer after pixel are moved to the canvas.